# Is there a work around for the conflict with the cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated and cordova ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

Im creating an Ionic 6.0 Cordova 9.0 project and I'm attempting to add the cordova fcm plugin in addition to the Cordova iOS 5.1.1 but it's failing in the build.

Here is my package json

```js
    "cordova": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^7.3.0",
```

what's odd is Cordova says 8.0.0 which is really

```js
cordova -v
9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

But the real problem is attempting to build the iOS project

```js
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-fzuncmihunbgyyfsixovlktiuyaf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app\ Mingle.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate+FCMPlugin.o /Users/anonymous/project/app-v5/platforms/ios/Heathen\ Mingle/Plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/AppDelegate+FCMPlugin.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

and then when I attempt to open in xCode I get a similar error in this specific line of code:

```js
- (void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"Device FCM Token: %@", deviceToken);
    if(deviceToken == nil) {
        fcmToken = nil;
        [FCMPlugin.fcmPlugin notifyFCMTokenRefresh:nil];
        return;
    }
```

Nullability specifier 'nonnull' conflicts with existing specifier 'nullable'

I don't have an issue with Android, only with iOS and this conflict.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I used this plugin instead
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^5.0.1",

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. I am afraid changing the plugin can have bigger problems in the project itself. Did you try this solution for an existing project or a new one? Do you have any other solution?

Comment: I tried it for an existing product. I uninstalled the older one and installed cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As a hot fix, you can delete "nonnull" keyword in the "- (void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)deviceToken {" error statement. This helped me succeed in building the app.

I followed these steps for a successful build:

1. cd platforms/ios
2. pod repo update
3. pod install
4. cd ..
5. cd ..

Now Delete plugins folder, platforms folder and the node_modules folder. (Step 6, 7 and 8)

9. npm i
10. ionic cordova platform add ios
11. ionic cordova build ios

( I know I couldve just said I updated pod repo and re installed node modules, plugins and platform but alot of new devs might have wasted some more time figuring out these commands, so yeah! )